# Declaration of variables within a loop

Tags: java, c++, loops

I have a very basic question about scoping rules. When you declare a variable within a loop, say:

```
while ( /*some condition*/ )
{
  int a = 0;
  //Remaining operations
}
```

Is a new `int` variable declared in every iteration of the loop? Or is it that `a` is destroyed at the end of every iteration and freshly created again? How does the compiler in Java or C++ understand and implement this?

Comment: What would the difference be?

Comment: Note that this isn't an OOP question; it's about scoping rules, which are specific to different languages. FWIW, an `int` variable, as in this case, will usually simply be assigned a register by the compiler.

Comment: When you ask a good question you no need to worry about downvotes.

Comment: I think this depends on the compiler..

Comment: @ruchira : didn't know this qualified as good question :) was just coding away in android when this hit me :)

Comment: @david: I just wanted to know the inner workings of this kind of code in object oriented programming because it is unique to OOPS.

Comment: It's most likely going to end up in the same space on the stack in each iteration.  So whether you say "destroyed and re-created" or just "re-used" is a semantic distinction only, not a real implementational difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to differentiate between the logical level and the implementation level.

From a logical point of view, the variable is not really 'created' or 'destroyed', but that's how you could probably imagine it. The variable is simply *declared* within some *scope*, so it's guaranteed to exist (you can assign to it and read its value), it's initialized at the beginning of the block (so it has the value `0`) and it isn't *visible* outside the code block. Thats what the language definition says. In C++, if you omit the initialization (i.e. the `=0` part),  the language doesn't make any assumption about what the value is (so the compiler is free to "reuse" the memory location). In Java, afair, the initialization is implicit, so `a` will also be set to zero, if you omit the initialization.

At implementation level, the compiler is more or less free to do whatever it wants, as long as it fulfills the above specifications. So in practise, it will most likely reserve some space on the stack and use this same memory for every iteration to store the value of `a`. Since you've used an initializer, the value `0` will be written to this location at the beginning of every loop. Note, that if `a` isn't used within the scope, the compiler is also free to simply optimize it away. Or, if possible, it can assign it to a CPU register.

However, theoretically, a compiler could also reserve a "new" memory location for `a` in every iteration and clear all of them at the end of the loop (although this could result in StackOverflow (!) for long loops...). Or use garbage-collected dynamic memory allocation (which would result in poor performance...).

Comment: Bear in mind if you do: `X a(0);` where X is a class, the constructor will be called at the beginning of each iteration, and the destructor on the end of each iteration. Unless the compiler can determine that "calling the constructor & destructor doesn't do anything".

Answer (score 2):

I find it easier to think about `a` as being the same variable that gets repeatedly created and destroyed.

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev: I don't mind other people editing my answers, but it's always nice to get a comment explaining the reasons behind major edits like this one.

Comment: That was by mistake, but I fixed it, didnt I?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, a is a local variable, which is initialized every iteration in the loop with the value 0, and then destroyed, and so on, until the loop is finished when it is ultimately destroyed

Note:

```
 while(//Some Condition)
```

would comment out the right parenthesis, and therefore the code would not run anyway

Correct this to:

```
while(/* some condition */)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's declared only in source code. In bytecode it simply uses a local variable on the stack which will be initialized with 0 at every iteration. The difference with declaration outside the loop is that when it is inside loop JVM will reuse the variable which `a` occupied.

Answer (score 1):

`a` create and destroyed after each and every iteration.